# How does elasticsearch schedule shards for query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a cluster with 11 nodes, and a table with 16 shard. Each shard has one replica. The allocation of the shards are like the follow. I added a number with ' for a replica. For example, 4 is the primary node, and 4' is 4's replica.

```html
    node             shards</br>
    0                5'   11'  12'</br>
    1                5    13   14'</br>
    2                1'     4'</br>
    3                6     7     8'</br>
    4                10'  14   15'</br>
    5                 3'    6'    11</br>
    6                 2     9'     12</br>
    7                 0'     1      3</br>
    8                 0 .    2' .    8</br>
    9                 4 .    7' .   13'</br>
    10               9 .    10 .   15</br>
```

For a query, the profile API shows that it always pick between two query plans like the following

```html
node         shards</br>
1                5    14'</br>
3                6     7</br>
    5                 11</br>
    6                 9'     12</br>
    7                 1     3</br>
    8                 0 .    2' .    8</br>
    9                 4 .    13'</br>
    10               10 .   15</br>
```

```html
 node           shards
 0                5'   12'</br>
 1                13</br>
 2                1'     4'</br>
 3                8'</br>
 4                14</br>
 5                 3'    6'    11</br>
 7                 0'  </br>
 8                 2' </br>
 9                 7' </br>
 10               9 .    10 .   15</br>
```

We can see that in the first schedule copies 0, 2 and 4 run on the node 8, while the 2nd schedule also has nodes running 3 copies.

Actually there exists a scheduling that ensures that each node has maximal 2 shards:

```html
    node         shards</br>
    1                5    14'</br>
    2                1'     4'</br>
    3                7 </br>
    4                15'</br>
    5                 6 . 11</br>
    6                 9'     12</br>
    7                 0'     3</br>
    8                 2'    8</br>
    9                 4 .   13'</br>
    10              10</br>
```

Why does not ES choose the last scheduling to reduce the number of copies running on a node?

Does ES have any other consideration so that it cannot schedule in the other way?

Thank you,